# What does x=[-300:1.1:300]'; mean?

Tags: matlab

In the code :

```
x=[-300:1.1:300]';
```

I don't understand what the single quote is for. What does this entire line mean?

I thought this syntax meant, x takes values from -300 to 300, with steps of 1.1.

A fragment of my code is:

```
x=[-300:1.1:300]';  
y=x;  
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
```

I am plotting a graph here.

Comment: The square brackets are creating a redundant copy. They are concatenation operators, but you use them with a single argument and therefore serve no purpose. Better use round brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. The single quote is for transpose. It changes x from a row vector to a column vector. Probably meshgrid wants columns, not  rows.

Comment: The single quote is complex conjugate transpose. It not only transposes the matrix, it also conjugates the complex values in the matrix. To transpose you should always use `.'`, even if in this case their results are the same. Getting used to the right syntax from the beginning will avoid bugs later on.

Comment: Why is there a need to transpose the x matrix? Can't I have a mesh with row matrices?